# synchronize(wait/notify) pattern in multiple streams in Spark

Tags: multithreading, spark-streaming

I have two Spark streams running in my application. At some point i need to see if first stream has created a table , so that i can use that Table in second stream.
I am using Accumulator as an indicator. So first stream updates the value of this accumulator after doing its job, and then the second stream executes its logic if the accumulator value has changed

```
dStream1.foreachRdd(rdd -> {
--creates ABC Sql table --
accumulator1.setValue(1);
});


dStream2.foreachRdd(rdd -> {
if(accumulator.value == 1){
--uses ABC Sql table--
}
});
```

so far it works fine, as dStream2 keeps on running the foreachRdd loop , and when it finds the accumulator value to be 1, it executes the logic.

But i want to find out more efficient way in which dStream2 waits until the value of accumulator changes. 
Is it possible to do wait-notify pattern in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

If we are running multiple streams, then the "foreachRDD" is executed one at a time. So they will not conflict with each other if they are sharing any resource or working on a common object.

Even if you want to use "spark.streaming.concurrentJobs" to run the streams or jobs parallely, you can manage the concurrency by using "java.util.concurrent.locks" package.